# How to check if a property constains a space in groovy?

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, constraints

I am new to grails, and I am having a problem on how to write the proper constraints of one of the properties of my class. I want to check if the input contains a space (' '). Here is my code..

```
static constraints = {    

username nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 6, matches: /[A-za-z0-9_]{6,}/, validator: { 
           Account.countByUsername(it) < 1  
        }
```

Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a custom validator like:

```
username validator: { val -> if (val.contains(' ')) return 'value.hasASpace' }
```

Edit: As R. Valbuena pointed out, you would need to change your `countByUsername()` validator to a `unique: true`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but once I have added that to my codes posted above, I got an error message pertaining to Account.countByUsername(it) < 1, is there any way to add your given validator without altering Account.countByUsername(it) < 1 ?

Comment: For username you probably want to define that constraint as username(unique:true) instead of doing the count query

Comment: @R. Valbuena is correct. Your countByUsername validator will cause validation to fail on any update. using unique:true is the way to go. FYI if you needed a custom validator to validate two conditions your validator would just check that both conditions were true.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! They are really of great help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a custom validator, you can also use the `matches` [validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Constraints/matches.html) to ensure that only valid characters are used.

It looks like you're using this in your original question and the regex you're using doesn't allow a space, so a username with a space should fail that validator.

If you want to give a special message to someone if they have a space in it (instead of some other invalid character), then doelleri's answer is the right way to do that.